# Nesting blocks - is the following problematic?

Tags: templating

I lazily added the following to my parent site template:

```
{% block body %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is this 'allowed' in Twig ?

Comment: Question title asks if it's a problem, body asks if it's allowed. Accepted answer says "Yes, see here". Will someone either edit the title to reflect permissibility, or the body and answer to reflect, err... problematicability? And yes, I just invented that word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the block tags docs. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#block-nesting-and-scope